# Unable to verify HMAC during Shopify EASDK

Tags: shopify, sha256

I'm working on an embedded app, and I can't get this to work at all... Here's the request that I'm receiving from Shopify to load my app:

```
http://myserver/myapp/?hmac=123&shop=myshop.myshopify.com&signature=abc&timestamp=1430425019
```

This all looks good to me, so I go through and remove the signature and hmac, and end up with this string

```
shop=myshop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1430425019
```

I then pass this off to my SHA256 handler, using the Credential Set defined in my app through the Partners login.

```
hmacSha256( "123abc", hashString) )
```

These values *never* match up. What am I doing wrong here? If I use the test values from the Shopify documentation regarding how the HMAC should be calculated, I get a matching value, so I know my HMAC function is working correctly.

Comment: Here are some notes that I've taken when verifying HMAC requests for EASDK:
1) ensure that all of the other params are included as well (not just `shop` and `timestamp`). Iterate through the query params you receive from Shopify and make sure all of them (except `hmac` and `signature`) are included in the string. (I know I receive `protocol` param as part of the request)
2) The order of the params matter. (it should be in alphabetical order). So `apple=orange&shop=myshop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1430425019` is different from `shop=myshop.myshopify.com&timestamp=1430425019&apple=orange`